# Share data between controllers with service

Tags: javascript, angular.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have to share data between controllers. In this example I'm using an aside. This has the exact same functionality as a modal from Angular Bootstrap.

I put the aside in my service so I can close it from another controller.

The problem is that I have to share the complete scope / object in the service so i can share the data between the controllers. In my real example, there are many lists in this object so it seems like it's a bit of overkill if I put the complete object in my service.

Is there a better way to do this?

I have to change the value from the scope on my page (= input field) but also in the aside. But the aside must have a different controller. Or can I use the same controller (`MainController`) for the aside? If I add the `MainController` to the aside, it instantiate the `MainController` again and the binding is lost. (See code example below)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L3sMfgXYpNHqUCJ9wPuO?p=preview)

```
AsideService.initAside($aside.open({
    placement: 'right',
    templateUrl: 'PropertiesSidebar.html',
    size: 'lg',
    controller: 'MainController'
  }));
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Your question can be better answered if you include a more substantial part of your code, as it's just one smaller file you can just include the whole of it.

Comment: I added a plunker link at the bottom of my question. There is all my code.

Comment: Yes, however it's still policy here to include the full code to be reviewed, see e.g. [this meta question](https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/asking-questions-including-full-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Having a model object owned by a service and referenced from multiple scopes is good practice. Having more references to the same object in this was isn't a cost you should worry about.

However the example could be improved with clearer layout and more meaningful naming. I would suggest something like the following style.

```
angular.module('asideApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAside'])

  .service('AsideService', function ($timeout) {
    var model = {
      aside: null,
      text: null
    };

    function initAside(aside) { shared.aside = aside; }

    return {
      model: model,
      initAside: initAside
    };
  })

  .controller('MainController', function ($scope, $aside, AsideService) {
    $scope.shared = AsideService.model;

    $scope.openAside = function () {
      AsideService.initAside($aside.open({
          placement: 'right',
          templateUrl: 'PropertiesSidebar.html',
          size: 'lg',
          controller: 'AsideController'
        }));
    };
  })

  .controller('AsideController', function ($scope, AsideService) {
    $scope.shared = AsideService.model;
  });
```